# Problemas com permissão ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION android studio

Tags: android, android-permission

Estou construindo um projeto que utiliza a classe *GsmCellLocation*. Posso conhecer tais informações a partir da classe *TelephonyManager*.

Para isto, preciso de permissões aí que nasce o problema. Uma permissão ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Ao chegar na linha abaixo, tenho retorno de exception, SecurityException.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
```

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getCellLocation: Neither user
>   10609 nor current process has
>   android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

Não há problemas na ordem de minhas permissões no manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Alguém já passou por isto...
Não faço ideia do que estou errando..
=T

Comment: Eu já publiquei uma resposta sobre essa questão de permissão, dê uma olhada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148189/35406

Answer (score -1):

A permissão ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION não está disponível para aplicativos que não fazem parte do firmware 'que no caso é o seu' porque as configurações  de segurança são projetadas para serem protegidos contra modificações por aplicativos de terceiros.

Comment: Onde você leu isso?

Comment: Também gostaria de saber a fonte. Isso não faz sentido pra mim, já que a permissão da pergunta serve para obter a localização por wifi ou triangulação de antenas . O que isso iria modificar no aparelho?

Comment: Alessandro.. Consegue mandar sua fonte sobre o assunto?
Também tenho interesse na leitura..