# A localização obtida por getLastLocation() retorna sempre nula

Tags: android, google-api, google-location-api

Estou realizando varias tentativas, mas não consigo obter a localização atual de um usuário utilizando da *Location API*.

Estou executando o exemplo a seguir:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

     Location localizacao;
     GoogleApiClient mapGoogleApiClient;
     EditText edtLat;
     EditText edtLog;
     Button btLocalizacao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edtLat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLatitude);
    edtLog = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLongitude);
    btLocalizacao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLocalizacao);

    if (mapGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mapGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    btLocalizacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GPS();
        }
    });
    }




    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void GPS() {
if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    localizacao = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mapGoogleApiClient);
    if (localizacao != null) {
        edtLat.setText(String.valueOf(localizacao.getLatitude()));
        edtLog.setText(String.valueOf(localizacao.getLongitude()));
    } else {
        AlertDialog erroLocation = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        erroLocation.setIcon(R.drawable.alert);
        erroLocation.setTitle("Localização não encontrada");
        erroLocation.setMessage("Sua Localização não foi encontrada!! Tente novamente!");
        erroLocation.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}}
```

O sistema roda perfeitamente, porem ele acaba todo momento caindo no else(código abaixo) do método GPS, pois não está passando a localização:

```
else {
    AlertDialog erroLocation = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    erroLocation.setIcon(R.drawable.alert);
    erroLocation.setTitle("Localização não encontrada");
    erroLocation.setMessage("Sua Localização não foi encontrada!! Tente novamente!");
    erroLocation.show();
}
```

Está pergunta não é duplicada, pois é um caso diferente e estava utilizando outros métodos para fazer funcionar. Resposta abaixo resolveu com sucesso essa pergunta.

Comment: Possível duplicata: ´[Como obter a localização atual do dispositivo android?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124634/28595)

Comment: Você está a testar em dispositivo físico ou no emulador?

Comment: Dispositivo físico e esta habilitado todos os serviços de localização.

Comment: de uma olhada no link sugerido pelo @diegofm e veja se resolve seu problema.

Comment: Entre na aplicação do Mapa, espere até a sua localização aparecer e volte a testar a sua aplicação, depois diga se o problema permanece..

Comment: @ramaral ja tentei fazer essa função, porem não retornou nenhuma coordenada..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como alertou o nosso amigo nos comentários, resolvi melhorar a resposta postando duas formas de capturar GPS, usando `GoogleApiClient` e usando `LocationManager`. Nas condições do Android 6.0(Api level 23) existe o [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) que trata-se da questão das permissões, que é bem interessante você dar lida e aprender mais.

## 1. Google Location API

> As APIs de localização facilitam a criação de aplicativos com ciência
>   da localização e baixo consumo de energia. Como a Google Maps Android
>   API, a Location API é distribuída como parte do SDK do Google Play
>   Services.

#### Classe Main

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    GoogleApiClient mapGoogleApiClient;
    EditText edtLat;
    EditText edtLog;
    Button btLocalizacao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_get_localization);

        edtLat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        edtLog = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        btLocalizacao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLocalizacao);

        if (mapGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mapGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        btLocalizacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (GetLocalization(Main.this)) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        return;
                    }
                    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mapGoogleApiClient);
                    if (location != null) {
                        edtLat.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                        edtLog.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                    } else {
                        showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mapGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mapGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public boolean GetLocalization(Context context){
        int REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION = 221;
        boolean res=true;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                res = false;
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION);

            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Este metodo exite uma alerta para configuração do GPS
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);

        // Titulo do dialogo
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS");

        // Mensagem do dialogo
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS não está habilitado. Deseja configurar?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Configurar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                Main.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // visualizacao do dialogo
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

## 2. LocationManager

Fiz alguns testes e criei uma classe chamada `ObtainGPS` para resolver o seu problema, que seria capturar sua atual localização (latitude/longitude). Nele também possui um método `showSettingsAlert()` que verifica se o GPS do dispositivo está habilitado, caso não esteja habilitado, o app te direciona para que você possa configurar/habilitar. 
Bom, na Main você apenas precisa declara o `ObtainGPS` além de criar um método `GetLocalization`. Então ficaria assim:

#### Classe Main

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    ObtainGPS gps;
    Button btLocalizacao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_get_localization);

        btLocalizacao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        btLocalizacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getLocalization();
            }
        });
    }

    public void getLocalization() {
        gps = new ObtainGPS(Main.this);


        if (GetLocalization(Main.this)) {
            // check if GPS enabled
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                AlertDialog erroLocation = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                erroLocation.setTitle("Localização");
                erroLocation.setMessage("Lat:" + gps.getLatitude() + " Lng:" + gps.getLongitude());
                erroLocation.show();

            } else {

                AlertDialog erroLocation = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                erroLocation.setTitle("Localização não encontrada");
                erroLocation.setMessage("Sua Localização não foi encontrada!! Tente novamente!");
                erroLocation.show();
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    }

    public boolean GetLocalization(Context context) {
        int REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION = 221;
        boolean res = true;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.

                res = false;
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION);

            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Uma observação que aqui estou usando `getLastKnownLocation`

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

#### Classe ObtainGPS

```
public class ObtainGPS extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public ObtainGPS(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;

        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }

                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS não está habilitado. Você deseja configura-lo?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Screenshots

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei [um repositório](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/obtgps/) no Github com nome [**obtgps**](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/obtgps/) pegando cordeadas usando duas formas. Você pode baixar o projeto e fazer as devidas verificações.

#### Detalhes

- [Intensões do Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Cara eu só não te abraço porque não te conheço KKK muito obrigado, testei as duas formas e era exatamente o que eu não estava conseguindo entender e fazer, mas devido a esta explicação funcionou perfeitamente! Melhor Resposta!

Comment: @GabrielHenrique Não estou fazendo nada mais nada menos que retribuir o que o Stackoverflow faz por todos, junto também com o Ramaral e muitos outros. Abraços.

Comment: SOCORRO, estou tentando estudar (android studio E JAVA) e esse codigo eh bem oque estou fazendo agora, mas como **sou novata**, estou apanhando bastante...  `por favor...` onde devo colocar cada um destes componentes para que funcione e eu possa estudar melhor?? tem um exemplo pra eu baixar? OBRIGADA!

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto foi você que fez a outra pergunta lá né?! Pois é! Eu esta meio sem tempo e não consegui te responder. Qualquer coisa amanha coloco para você baixar como exemplo.

Comment: @AckLay bacana!!!  obrigado pela atenção! vou aguardar  ansiosa !!  vocês estão me ensinando bastante! são muito lindos!

Answer (score 4):

Apesar da sua implementação ser mínima, para obter a localização julgo que só falta chamar `mapGoogleApiClient.connect()`.

Faço o *overrride* dos métodos `onStart()` e `onStop()` assim:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mapGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```