# Google maps android já abrir procurando posição atual

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Gostaria de ajuda para conseguir fazer o google maps da minha aplicação android já procurar a posição atual do usuário assim que o mapa for aberto,  da mesma forma dos gps tradicionais, como o waze, ser ter q clicar em algum botão para isso.

E em conjunto com isso, se é possível fazer o mapa já abrir com algum zoom. Porque caso o usuário nao esteja conectado com gps ou wifi, o mapa pelo menos já estivesse mostrando o estado de São Paulo em vez de estar sem nenhum zoom como é o padrão. Obrigado.

Comment: Use [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148189/35406) que coloquei em outra pergunta! Já vai te ajudar!

Comment: Você está executando a aplicação no emulador ou num dispositivo via USB?

Comment: No celular mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra você abrir seu mapa em um lugar específico você pode usar:

```
 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(-23.572847, -46.629716))      // Define o centro do mapa para localização do usuário em São Paulo
        .zoom(17)                   // Define zoom
        .bearing(90)                // Define a orientação da câmera para leste
        .tilt(30)                   // Define a inclinação da câmara para 30 graus
        .build();                   // define uma posição da câmera do construtor
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Para que seja capturado sua localização, você pode seguir [esta minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148189/35406) em outra pergunta. Após a implementação, para você já abrir o mapa sem ter que clicar em algum botão, você vai inserir este código abaixo no seu `onCreate`:

```
        if (GetLocalization(this)) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main.this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                return;
            }
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mapGoogleApiClient);
            if (location != null) {
                edtLat.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                edtLog.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            } else {
                showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
```

Redirecionamento para as configurações caso o GPS esteja desativado:

```
    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS não está habilitado. Você deseja configura-lo?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

#### Detalhes

- [Objetos de Mapa](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#configure_initial_state)

Comment: Olá amigo. Primeiramente obrigado. Estou tentando implementar a explicação que você deu no outro post, usando o LocationManager ...porém na linha " if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)...." Essa parte do "ACESS_FINE_LOCATION" e na COURSE LOCATION aparece como erro. Sabe oq posso fazer para consertar? As permissões já estão liberadas no meu arquivo Manifest. Obrigado.

Comment: @Omnislade Qual o erro?

Comment: Fica em vermelho, como se eu não tivesse liberada as permissões no meu arquivo Manifest, porém elas já estão liberadas.

Comment: @Omnislade fica vermelho na classe ou no XML?

Comment: Amigo, deu certo. Precisei dar um Clear no projeto pra ele ficar normal. Porém, ainda continuo com um único problema no comando "showSettingsAlert();". Aparece como "Cannot resolve method", alguma sugestão?

Comment: É possivel em vez de eu ter que clicar no botão que foi criado lá no main, o "btLocalizacao" eu poder clicar no botão que é criado pelo ".setMyLocationEnabled(true)" para fazer a mesma coisa?

Comment: @Omnislade esse showSettingsAlert() está logo abaixo lá no projeto. Ele serve para quando seu GPS estiver desligado, te redirecionar para as configurações para você habilitar. Quanto ao setMyLocalizationEnabled(true), acredito que sim.

Comment: Entçao ..mais esse "shoSettingAlert()" está dando erro quando escrevo ele. E eu vou ver se consigo colocar no setMyLocalizationEnable essa função do botao, pq nao tenho botao nem editext no meu projeto, só abre o mapa direto com a localização.

Comment: @Omnislade você vai conseguir usando `mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener`.

Comment: Estou dando um jeito aqui para conseguir deixar tudo OK, mais ainda não consegui arrumar a parte do showSettingsAlert(). Eu preciso implementar alguma coisa para esse código funcionar?

Comment: @Omnislade editei a resposta e adicionei o `showSettingsAlert()`.. Abraços

Comment: Muito obrigado. Vou testar aqui mais é isso mesmo que preciso.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se o exemplo ajuda, só não sei fazer funcionar emulador.

** No AndroidManifest.XML adicionar

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

** Gradle script (Module app) dependences adicionar

```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
```

**

```
//-------------------------------------

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{

  protected GoogleMap m_map;

  //-----------------------------------

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  }

  //-----------------------------------

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
  {
    m_map = googleMap;

    m_map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    UiSettings ui = m_map.getUiSettings();

    ui.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    try {
      checkCnn();
      checkGps();

      new MyLocation().execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      // Tratar error

      Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  //-----------------------------------

  public void checkCnn() throws Exception
  {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeNetwork == null) {
      throw new Exception("wi-fi off");
    }
  }

  //-----------------------------------

  public void checkGps() throws Exception
  {
    LocationManager manager;

    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
      throw new Exception("gps off");
    }
  }

  //-----------------------------------

  protected class MyLocation implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
  {
    private GoogleApiClient m_api;

    //---------------------------------

    public MyLocation()
    {
      super();
    }

    //---------------------------------

    protected void execute()
    {
      m_api = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                      .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                      .build();

      m_api.connect();
    }

    //-----------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
    {
      LatLng latLng = location();

      m_map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
      m_map.animateCamera(cameraPosition(latLng,15,0,0));
      //m_map.moveCamera(cameraPosition(latLng,15,0,0));

      m_api.disconnect();
    }

    //---------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {
    }

    //---------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {
    }

    //---------------------------------

    public CameraUpdate cameraPosition(LatLng latLng, float zoom, float tilt, float bearing)
    {
      CameraPosition.Builder builder = new CameraPosition.Builder();

      CameraPosition position = builder.target(latLng)
                                        .zoom(zoom)
                                        .tilt(tilt)
                                        .bearing(bearing)
                                        .build();

      return CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position);
    }

    //---------------------------------

    public LatLng location()
    {
      Location loc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(m_api);

      return new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude());
    }

    //-----------------------------------

  } // end MyLocation

  //-----------------------------------

} // end class

//-------------------------------------
```

Comment: Vou tentar aqui e já te flo amigo.