# Pegar latitude e longitude no Android

Tags: android

Eu estou criando um aplicativo no Android (com Android Studio) de Compras. A ideia é cadastrar uma compra no app que o usuario realizou.
O que queria é na hora que fazer isso pegar a latitude e longitude de onde ele esta.

Perguntou qual classe e método utilizo para isto no Android?

Me refiro ao Android 5, 6 pra cima.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2227299/3792998

Comment: Só tem que lembrar, que se o SDK que você estiver usando para compilar for maior que API 23 (Android 6.0) você deve inserir as permissões em tempo de execução, você pode encontrar detalhes [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission#34722591)

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni no Android 6 tudo precisa pedir em Run Time? (as permissões)

Comment: @LuizaCH Sim, mas dependendo do seu caso você não precisa usar a API 23 ou maior para compilar, se você compilar com a API 22 (Android 5.1.1), quando seu app for instalado em android 6.0 ou superior, as permissões já virão automaticamente habilitado, esta [imagem](https://fscl01.fonpit.de/userfiles/7157649/image/permissoes-android-4-w782.jpg) demonstra isso

Comment: @LuizaCH eu publiquei uma resposta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148189/35406) na pergunta: "A localização obtida por getLastLocation() retorna sempre nula", que será útil para você.

Comment: melhor ponto de partida é sempre a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/building-location.html)