# Problema em pegar latitude e longitude

Tags: java, android, geolocalização

Meu codigo estava funcionado, pegava a latitude e longitude normalmente, porem parou e não estou mais conseguindo pegar a localização.So cai na condição de que não foi possivel pegar a localização

```
  private void foto(int actionCode) {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final boolean GPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (GPSEnabled) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        switch (actionCode) {
            case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
                File f = null;
                try {
                    f = setUpPhotoFile();
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    } else {
                        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    }
                    if (location != null) {
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "Não foi possivel obter sua localização" +
                                "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    f = null;
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = null;

                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        } // switch
```

Comment: Coloca um `Log.d` dentro desta if: `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { Log.i("MINHA_TAG", "Sem permissão"); }`

Comment: Coloquei, porem não passa por esse Log

Comment: getLastKnownLocation retorna na verdade a ultima posição registrada, talvez ele não tenha conseguido registrar a sua ultima posição, abre o google maps peça pra localizar você e depois abre teu app só pra testar.

Comment: Fiz isso e não funcionou, porem tenho um app Status do Gps, quando abro ele e ele pega localização, abro meu app dai funciona, porem quando salvo no banco so fica  na mesma localização, independente de onde vou.

Comment: Mas perai a questão é banco ou GPS? Ok, vamos por partes, primeiro veja isto `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)` (o link do android.com quebra, copia e cola no navegador)

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está só verifica se há permissão, mas não solicita que a permissão seja concedida. Abaixo segue um método que que verifica e já concede permissão usando [**`requestPermissions()`**](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) através da interação com usuário:

```
public boolean getPermissionLocalization(Context context) {
        int REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION = 221;
        boolean res = true;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.

                res = false;
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION);

            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Aí antes de você solicitar, faça a seguinte verificação:

```
if(getPermissionLocalization(this)){
    // permissão concedida
} else {
    // permissão não concedida
}
```

Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148189/35406) para mais detalhes.

Comment: No meu telefone ele não esta passando por esse if que solicita a permissão de localização. Tenho as premissoes no manifest tbm

Comment: @JulianoMorche Esse if eu acabei de criar aí na resposta. Estou dizendo para você adaptar ao seu código. Você tentou fazer isso?

Comment: Bom , coloquei como vc disse, e ele cai na opçao concedida