# Dificuldade com Permissão Location Android

Tags: java, android, android-permission

Estou a tentar colocar a funcionar um projecto *open-source* encontrado na internet mas estou com alguns problemas ao tentar implementar as permissões para o Location agora exigidas pelo compileSdkVersion 23 e buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" que quero utilizar.

O código em que estou a usar pode ser encontrado aqui: https://github.com/vyshane/rex-weather

```
/**
 * Implement an Rx-style location service by wrapping the Android LocationManager and providing
 * the location result as an Observable.
 */
public class LocationService {
    private final LocationManager mLocationManager;


    public LocationService(LocationManager locationManager) {
        mLocationManager = locationManager;
    }

    public Observable<Location> getLocation() {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super Location> subscriber) {

                final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                        subscriber.onNext(location);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();

                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    }

                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    }
                };

                final Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();
                locationCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                locationCriteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
                final String locationProvider = mLocationManager
                        .getBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);

                Looper.prepare();

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                mLocationManager.requestSingleUpdate(locationProvider,
                        locationListener, Looper.myLooper());

                Looper.loop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

O meu problema está no 'this' da permissão, o qual tem como erro o seguinte:

> checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,String)in
>   ContextCompat cannot be applied
>
> to(anonymous
>   rx.Observable.OnSubscribe,String)

Eu não sei como colocar isto a funcionar, se alguém me puder dar uma ajuda agradecia.

---

Eu usei o add permission check automático e deu o seguinte:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
```

Só que dá erro no "this" e eu não sei como resolver isso, e o erro decorrente é:

> checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,String)in ContextCompat cannot be applied
>   to(anonymous rx.Observable.OnSubscribe,String)

Answer (score 1):

A dificuldade não está no uso de permissões mas sim no entendimento do que representa a palavra chave [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

[ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Context, String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) recebe no 1º parâmetro um objecto do tipo [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

O código está usando `this` como argumento para esse parâmetro:

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), dentro de um método de instância ou construtor, refere-se ao objecto actual.
Para o poder usar em `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()` esse objecto tem de ser do tipo *Context*.

A chamada ao método está a ser feita dentro de um método de uma classe(interface) anónima do tipo *Observable.OnSubscribe*.
Usando `this` neste contexto, está a passar um objecto do tipo *Observable.OnSubscribe* quando é esperado um tipo *Context*, daí o erro:

> checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,String)in ContextCompat cannot be applied
>   to(anonymous rx.Observable.OnSubscribe,String)

Para a classe *LocationService* poder usar o método `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()` terá de ter disponível um *Context*.
Uma forma possível de o disponibilizar é passá-lo ao construtor,

```
public class LocationService {
    private final LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private final Context mContext;

    public LocationService(Context context, LocationManager locationManager) {
        mLocationManager = locationManager;
        mContext = context;
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

que poderá ser utilizado no método `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()` assim:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
           Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
           Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nas condições do Android 6.0(Api level 23) existe o [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) que trata-se da questão das permissões, que é bem interessante você dar lida e aprender mais. Você tem que usar o `requestPermissions` para liberar a permissão para utilizar a localização:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION);
```

Dê uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148189/35406), que vai te esclarecer melhor.