# Como colocar um PopUp que pede autorização para usar o GPS?

Tags: java, android

Gente, estou programando em Java (com Android Studio) e este código para pegar a posição do GPS, que funciona muito bem!

Agora eu estou tentando aprender como **pedir autorização ao usuário** para usar o GPS, mas encontrei "informação de mais" no google... E nada mais parece se encaixar...

Claro que só pode ser porque sou novata e não estou entendendo algo:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
Location l = LocationServices
        .FusedLocationApi
        .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

if(l != null){
    accuracy = l.getAccuracy();
    locationLatLng = new LatLng(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());
    //garantee to get the "GPS position"  and only after that, show the map.
    if(map != null){
        setMarker(locationLatLng);
    }
}
```

Então gostaria de dividir minha pergunta em três partes:

1. Como é e/ou como funciona essa parte de "pedir" autorização? Não tem uma regra simples pra seguir?
2. Como ajustar meu android (versão 5.1) para "bloquear o GPS" e obrigar que cada APP peça novamente para usá-lo? Preciso testar repetidamente e bloquear várias vezes para poder repetir os testes!
3. Onde estou errando nesse código que ele não pede autorização (o popup não abre) e já sai usando o GPS? Seria alguma config do meu android?

Desculpem se não fui clara, estou aprendendo! Me corrijam, por favor!

PS: eis o código completo da minha classe, acho que facilita o entendimento:

```
package jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;
import jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.model.Report;

import static jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.config.Constants.MAP_ZOOM;


/**
 * Created by ootaegd on 2016/12/16.
 */

public class PostPositionActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Marker marker = null;
    private LatLng locationLatLng;
    private float accuracy;
    private String uuId;
    protected Realm realm;
    private TextView tvCoordinate;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_position);

        //前のactivityから渡されたデータを取得する
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        uuId = intent.getStringExtra("uuId");

        //realm設定
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

        //toolbarを設定
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.post_position_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.headPositionTitle));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        onBtnGpsClicked();
        nextViewActivity();

        //Fragment を取得
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // Start GPS Procedures
        callConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Getting the Google GPS API OnLine.
     */
    private synchronized void callConnection() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Getting the actual GPS position.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location l = LocationServices
                .FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(l != null){
            accuracy = l.getAccuracy();
            locationLatLng = new LatLng(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());
            //garantee to get the "GPS position"  and only after that, show the map.
            if(map != null){
                setMarker(locationLatLng);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    /**
     * 次の画面へ遷移する処理
     */
    private void nextViewActivity() {
        //位置情報ボタンを押された時の処理
        Button btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);
        btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //位置情報を追加する
                addReport();

                // 画面を起動
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki", "jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.PostConfirmationActivity");
                intent.putExtra("uuId",uuId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * 現在地取得ボタンを押された時、現在地を取得する
     */
    private void onBtnGpsClicked() {
        Button btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
        btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //現在地取得
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * GoogleMapを読み込む前に、オーバライドして処理を行う
     *
     * @param googleMap
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady( GoogleMap googleMap ) {
        map = googleMap;

        //garantee to get the "GPS position"  and only after that, show the map.
        if(locationLatLng != null){
            setMarker(locationLatLng);
        }

        // GoogleMapが押下された時の処理
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick( LatLng latLng ){
                // クリックされるたびにマーカが増えていく
                // 一つ前のマーカは削除する
                marker.remove();
                //Mapが押下されたらその位置にピンを立てる
                //緯度経度を取得
                locationLatLng = latLng;
                //garantee to get the "GPS position"  and only after that, show the map.
                if(locationLatLng != null){
                    //ピンを立てる
                    setMarker(locationLatLng);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Markerを立てる関数
     *
     * @param lacation　緯度経度情報
     */
    private void setMarker(LatLng lacation){
        marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(lacation)
                .title("報告場所")
                .draggable(false));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lacation, MAP_ZOOM));
    }

    /**
     * 位置情報を追加する
     * @return プライマリキー
     */
    private void addReport(){

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        //トランザクション開始
        realm.beginTransaction();
        //uuIdでターゲットを抽出
        Report report = realm.where(Report.class).equalTo("key",uuId).findFirst();
        //保存を行う
        report.setLat(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(locationLatLng.latitude)));
        report.setLon(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(locationLatLng.longitude)));
        report.setAccuracy(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(accuracy)));
        //トランザクション終了
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa fazer dois tipos de verificações se tratando de GPS. A a primeira é se seu GPS está habilitado e a segunda é caso você esteja usando API 23, você tem que usar [Solicitação de permissões em tempo de execução](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=pt-br). Vamos aos detalhes.

### Verificação 1

Para a primeira verificação, pode se criar um método que verifica se seu GPS está habilitado ou não. Caso não esteja habilitado ele emite uma mensagem perguntando se "você deseja configurar". Essa mensagem pode ser ajustável de acordo com suas preferências. Veja o código abaixo e adapte-o da forma que preferir:

```
 /**
 * Este metodo exite uma alerta para configuração do GPS
 */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);

    // Titulo do dialogo
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS");

    // Mensagem do dialogo
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS não está habilitado. Deseja configurar?");

    // botao ajustar configuracao
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Configurar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // botao cancelar
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // visualizacao do dialogo
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Para chama-lo, você tem que primeiro fazer a verificação se a localização está nula ou não desta forma:

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mapGoogleApiClient);
if (location != null) {
    // aqui você captura lat e lgn caso o localização seja diferente de nul
} else {
    // caso contrario ele chama seu método
    showSettingsAlert();
}
```

### Verificação 2

A partir do Android 6.0 (nível de API 23), os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados. Então esta verificação é só para quem possui API 23 ou superior. Essa abordagem otimiza o processo de instalação de aplicativos, pois o usuário não precisa conceder permissões ao instalar ou atualizar o aplicativo.

Para verificar se você tem uma permissão, chame o método `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()`. Por exemplo, este snippet mostra como verificar se a atividade tem permissão para acessar localização:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Então basicamente você pode criar um método com retorno do tipo `boolean` desta forma:

```
public boolean getLocalization(Context context) {
    int REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION = 221;
    boolean res = true;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.

            res = false;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION);

        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Na verificação e execução do método, logo ele já vai mostrar uma alerta pedindo autorização. Então basta você verificar desta forma:

```
if(getLocalization(this)){
    //ao entrar aqui é porque já foi liberado
}
```

Na pergunta sobre "[A localização obtida por getLastLocation() retorna sempre nula](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148157/a-localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-obtida-por-getlastlocation-retorna-sempre-nula/148189#148189)", eu explico exatamente como deve ser feito para buscar localização por dois formas [Google Location API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=pt-br) e por [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). Vale a pensa você se orientar por lá também, onde eu mostro as duas formas.

Criei [um repositório](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/obtgps/) no Github com nome [**obtgps**](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/obtgps/) pegando cordeadas usando duas formas. Você pode baixar o projeto e fazer as devidas verificações.

Comment: BACANA! vou estudar !  assim que terminar volto pra explicar o que aconteceu!   OBRIGADA!

Comment: soh uma perguntinha...  aquele "checkSelfPermission" que eu fiz ali, bem an horade abrir o mapa.. esta errado??

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto exitei a resposta colocando um projeto lá no github.

Comment: MUIIITO bacana!!!  vou poder estudar!!!! FINALMENTE!!  brigadinha!!!!!!!!!!  depois volto com meus resultados!

Answer (score -1):

No seu manifest é onde ficam salvos os pedidos de permissão de tudo que o seu app possa usar, então basta adicionar as linhas:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Caso esteja usando como targetSDK 21 ou mais, pode precisar desta linha tb:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Fonte: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358491/3473971)

Se ele sai usando o GPS provavelmente é porque ele já está autorizado, eh um negocio dificil de testar.